# Disable clicking on the GIF image

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, sitepages, hero-web-part

I am using Hero Web part in SharePoint Online Page with the Tile layout option. Under this, I am using a GIF image as a Link like below:

[image]

Further, I am also using the Actions to include Learn More.

[image]

Now, the problem arises when the user clicks the GIF image and it opens in full screen. I would either like to make the GIF image unclickable or to redirect the user to the Learn More link when they click the GIF image.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same link you are using in "Call to action link" section under the **Link** option like:

[image]

[image]

Then when user clicks on the GIF, SharePoint will open the mentioned URL and not GIF.

1. Click on "Change" button under "Link" section
2. Select "From a link" option from left side when a panel opens
3. Paste your link (same as call to action link) and click "Add" button
4. Publish your page

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently I have the added the GIF image as a link under the "LINK" option. If I replace that with the link used in "Call to action link"  then hoe to add the GIF link.

Comment: Are you trying to show the GIF on page? If yes, you can add it under Background image > Custom image section.

Comment: Hi - Just checked. By adding the image as Custom Image, the image is static. GIF is not working. Any reason or solution?

Comment: I have tried it before answering here and GIF worked fine at my end. Note: I have "uploaded" GIF under background image section (not using link for background > custom image).